telegram api Работа с инлайном
Нужно сделать так, чтобы во время ввода текста появлялись инлайны как в InlineQueryResultArticle

Но при этом чтобы результат после нажатия кнопки можно было вывести как в InlineQueryResultPhoto

Возможно ли такое сделать, и если да, то как?

как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

@aleksandrbarakin так тут скорее вопрос не к коду, а к возможностям апи телеграма. Есть ли смысл в этом случае кидать код?
